# Django rest framework unauthenticated user get request error in testing

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, tdd

I'm trying to test the get request on the url which requires user to be authenticated. If user is unauthenticated it must return **HTTP_401 UNAUTHORIZED** error as response status code. For that purpose i've created a test case where i tried firing get request without authentication.

**TestCase**

```py
class PublicTagsApiTests(TestCase):
    """Test the publicly available tags API"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_login_required(self):
        """Test that login is required for retrieving tags"""
        res = self.client.get(reverse('recipe:tag-list'))
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

But the test fails returning error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

**View**

```py
class TagViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    """Manage tags in the database"""
    authentication_classes =  (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TagSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return objects for the current authenticated user only"""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-name')
```

**Serializer**

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for tag objects"""


    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id','name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

How can i modify my view to pass the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TagViewSet try to change:

```
permission = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

to:

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Comment: permission ---> permission_classes

Comment: Though ``permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`` works, whats the point in changing tuple to list?

Comment: is not the point of change tuple to list... the point is to change the name permission to permission_classes

Comment: Yup got that, but what;s the difference in using list and tuple?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203975/discussion-between-devprog-and-aprimus).